# How to validate the values in the context before saving to core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

How can we validate the context before saving it to core data?. My idea is i should have some validation before saving it into core data, if the values doesn't satisfy the validation the the coredata should not save the values. Say for example i have  attributes like name, class, age, etc for entity candidate. I should have a validation that the values shouldn't be nil. If it is nil then the other values should not be saved.

Can anybody help me in this regard

EDITED:
I need to check them only at the time of saving and that should be done with core data

Answer (score 0):

I like to do catchall validation in the save routine. Before you actually do the call to save the context, loop through its insertedObjects array and make sure they are as you require. If they aren't, you can either delete them or alert the user that they need to complete something (if the latter, return out of the method; give the user a chance to fix the problem).

Other validation should be at the point of entry, when you are getting values from, say, a textfield or checkbox to assign to your managed objects. Let the user know right away if there's a problem.

Also check out NSNumberFormatter, which can be applied to fields, preventing user from making incorrect entries to begin with.

Comment: Say for example, i need an attribute as key and if that attribute is not nil then only the other values in the context should be saved to core data. Is there any thing like that? @Wienke

Comment: Right, I was misconstruing your question. I’ve posted another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Coredata validate itself when inserting its values. In managedObject class we can write our custom validation so that coredata will check that validation before saving the values. If the value is not valid then those values in the context will not be saved to coredata.

Here i added

```
@interface
-(BOOL) validateForInsert:(NSError **)error;

@implementation
-(BOOL) validateForInsert:(NSError **)error {
   // check the value of the field with validation
     if(condition == true) {
      return Yes;
     }
 return NO;
}
```

(NSError **) is a special parameter that makes the coredata to call this method as if like a delegate method

Comment: There's some confusion here: To save the object is to save the context with the object in it -- which can't happen unless the object has already been inserted into the context. Also, NSError does not call the method. You pass an empty NSError by reference and the method fills it if an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I hadn’t read your question carefully enough when I made that first answer. You’re not validating that individual entries for individual attrs are correct, rather, that no changes should be saved unless *all* attrs are filled for that object.

Looking at Apple doc “[Model Object Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdValidation.html)”, you are concerned with *inter*-property validation, not property validation, and you are on the right track to be thinking of using `validateForInsert:` for this purpose.

That doc also supplies examples. Here’s a possible implementation for the particular entity you describe:

```
- (BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError **)error {
if (self.name && self.class && self.age)
    return [super validateForInsert:error];
else
    return NO;
}
```

However, this method happens at the insertion stage, not at the save stage.

If you are gathering entries for a new entity all at once, validating at the insertion stage would make sense — don’t add a new object to the context if that object is doomed to be discarded as incomplete.
If you are gathering entries for changes to an existing object, and you want to make sure that all those changes work together before accepting any of them, `validateForUpdate:` would make sense — but there would be no way to restore the object to its original state other than by reopening the context without saving, unless you had cached its original values elsewhere.
If you want to gather attrs individually and wait to check that they are all complete before saving the object, I think you would do as I first suggested: Loop through the context’s insertedObjects and take care of validation before actually saving the context. There’s no existing `validateForSave:` method to override, but you could add one.

You could also combine these techniques: Gather entries and make new objects without inserting them, but cache all these objects in an array. When it comes time to save, loop through the cache and insert the objects into the context only if they pass `validateForInsert:`; then save the context.

Obviously I’m learning along with you, so the above might not be quite the cookie. Hopefully that Apple doc will be enough to get you started.

Comment: The new link is: [Object Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/ObjectValidation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH20-SW4). Also, in the first two lines of validateForInsert:, you're confusing property-level validation ('[super validateForInsert:error]') and and inter-property or consistency validation  (self.name && self.class && self.age). First do the property-level validation, *then* check the consistency. As your code stands now, neither name, nor class nor age can ever be set.